# How to add New values into a table from a different table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have recently migrated from Access backend to SQL Server. I have my front end in MS Access and backend in SQL Server. Now whenever a new client is created by the user, a stored procedure runs automatically which actually splits the data from the main table into different tables eg: The client table would have all the data and then it would be split into different tables like Address, Phone, etc. Now every time the stored procedure runs all the values from the client's table is inserted into other tables as all the value is duplicated. I just want the new values to be inserted into different tables and not the old values which are already present there.

Stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ClientRelationstbl]
           ([CNR](FK)
           ,[RelationTypeID]
           ,[FirstName]
           ,[Surname]
           ,[LastUpdated]
           ,[UpdatedBy]
           ,[Active])
     SELECT
            [CNR](PK)
           ,1
           ,[FNM]
           ,[SNM]
           ,GETDATE()
           ,124
           ,1
    FROM [dbo].[clientstbl]
    WHERE [FNM] IS NOT NULL 
       OR [SNM] IS NOT NULL
       AND [CNR] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [CNR] 
                         FROM [ClientRelationstbl])
```

[FNM] = FirstName Mother
[SNM] = Surname Mother

Now, whenever I try to run this it stores duplicate values in the table. I just want to store the new values in the ClientRelation table.

Comment: If you've migrated to SQL Server, why have you migrated to a version that has been *completely* unsupported for 3 years?

Comment: I would migrate to a current version of SQL Server (not 2008). That version can have security holes that are not going to be fixed ever.

Comment: Post the stored procedure code - all of it. But it seems your design is faulty. Your insert statement is not based on a specific client though you do attempt to limit the client rows considered based on CNR (if my guess is correct). And your code suffers from a lack of parentheses around the various and/or conditions.

Comment: `Where ([CNR] = xx and ( [FNM] is not null or [SNM] is not null )` This is my guess about the WHERE clause you should be using. I used "xx" to represent the ID of the customer that was just created. Your procedure creates a customer - it should **know** the primary key values of that created row.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your reply. I'm really sorry I added the tag "SQL-server-2008" instead of "SQL-server-2017". Apologies once again.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I should have added sql2017 instead of sql2008. I have updated it. Apologies once again. :)|

Comment: You can also use "Merge"  to insert, update and delete. We use it to automate changes to push to an existing table.

Comment: @SMor Thanks for your reply. The whole procedure is the same just the field names are different. Yes, you are absolutely correct, I'm attempting to limit the client rows bases on CNR.  I will try and add parenthesis to the query. I will check and let you know.

Comment: @NonProgrammer Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me how can I use "Merge" in SQL?

Comment: I hate to just post a link due to lack of time at this moment. MERGE statement allows you to update, insert, delete in one statement without writing seperate logic for all three. You put this into a stored procedure and schedule it to run based on the need. You can also save logs to a table to review. It will show you what rows were updated/deleted/inserted. Keep in mind MERGE works for unique rows else it gives an error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Please use "NOT EXISTS" instead of "NOT IN":

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[clientrelationstbl]
            ([Cnr](fk),
             [relationtypeid],
             [firstname],
             [surname],
             [lastupdated],
             [updatedby],
             [active])
SELECT a.[Cnr](pk),
       1,
       a.[fnm],
       a.[snm],
       Getdate(),
       124,
       1
FROM   [dbo].[clientstbl] a
WHERE  (a.[fnm] IS NOT NULL OR a.[snm] IS NOT NULL)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.[cnr]
                             FROM [clientrelationstbl] b 
                             WHERE b.[Cnr] = a.[Cnr])
```

Comment: I think that you will miss some data that `[fnm]` or `[snm]` have been updated to new value. SP need to handle those exist data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will work on it and let you know how it went. Also, I didn't understand the part where you said I will miss some data that [fnm] and [snm] have.